# how to reset a checkbox behavior using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I have this function checkRule, when the value2 == "Exclusive", I call checkRule to allow select only specific Checkbox, when value2 != "Exclusive" i want to reset the checkbox behavior, to be alowed to select any of the boxes. How can I do that?

```
   if (value2 == "Exclusive") {
        if (RPDirect.checked == true) {
            for (var i = 0; i < Checkboxes.length; i++) {
                Checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", checkRule);
               } 
        } 
    }
   if (value2 != "Exclusive") {
            
        }

    function checkRule(e)  {
        if (Checkboxes[7].checked == false ) {
            alert("Public must be selected.")  
        } 
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two approaches you could take.

Following through with your current approach, you could use `removeEventListener` in the same was as you used `addEventListener` when `value2` is changed.

It would probably be **better**, however, to move any tests (such as `if (value2 == "Exclusive")`) which determine if a checkbox should be checked or not so they are **inside** `checkRule`.

Comment: Like you said, put the validation inside the function solved my problem, I putted (Checkboxes[7].checked == false && value2 === "Exclusive") and it works, thank you a lot!